# vscode prettier plugin lack of spaces breaks linter rule

Tags: javascript, prettier

On a node project my prettier plugin acts different than on projects created with create-react-app.

When I write code like:

```
var test = { a: 1
};
```

and save the file in a react app it pretties to:

```
var test = { a: 1 };
```

In the node project it pretties to:

```
 var test = {a: 1};
```

This will have the linter complain `A space is required before '}'.`

I can't figure out why prettier would behave differently for an app created with create-react app. The have the same vscode settings and the same prettier.yml.

I am using [Prettier code formatter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode)

This spaces problem prevents me from making pull requests because the code will fail the linter.

I guess I can create a bash script that auto fixes linting errors but was wondering why I would have to do this in the first place since the React apps don't have this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much can be said without seeing config files and Prettier setup.
Spacing before and after `{` and `}` is configured by `bracketSpacing: true` option in prettier config. You should check if it is specified in the config file: if not, theoretically, it can be pulled from elsewhere in your Node project.

Comment: That works, too bad it leaves me with at least one more [unsolvable problem](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/3161). Currently just fixing it with `eslint --fix`